# Assign a random array string to a text component - Unity 4.6, uGUI

Tags: c#, arrays, random, unity-game-engine

I'm creating an array with a list of descriptions (strings) that I need to choose randomly and then assign to a text component in a gamobject. How do I do that? I've created the array but I don't know where to go from there. Can anyone help me with this?

```
public string[] animalDescriptions = 
{
    "Description 1",
    "Description 2",
    "Description 3",
    "Description 4",
    "Description 5",
};


void Start () 
{

    string myString = animalDescriptions[0];
    Debug.Log ("You just accessed the array and retrieved " + myString);

    foreach(string animalDescription in animalDescriptions)
    {
        Debug.Log(animalDescription);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour 
{
public Text myText;

public string[] animalDescriptions = 
{
    "Description 1",
    "Description 2",
    "Description 3",
    "Description 4",
    "Description 5",
};

void Start()
{
    string myString = animalDescriptions [Random.Range (0, animalDescriptions.Length)];
    myText.text = myString;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string myString = animalDescriptions[new Random().Next(animalDescriptions.Length)];
```

You might want to store that `new Random()` somewhere else so that you don't seed a new one every time you want a new random description, but that's about it. You can do that by initializing your `Random` elsewhere, and simply using your instance of it in `Start`:

```
Random rand = new Random();
// ... other code in your class
void Start()
{
    string myString = animalDescriptions[rand.Next(animalDescriptions.Length)];
    // ... the rest of Start()
}
```

Comment: I popped that in but I'm getting an error on 'Next' : Assets/_Scripts/GameSetup.cs(23,67): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Random' does not contain a definition for `Next' and no extension method `Next' of type `UnityEngine.Random' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)